# Load Balance on Windows 7 Pro Desktop

Tags: windows-7, load-balancing

For development and testing purposes, I'd like to install two "web heads" and a database on my Windows 7 Pro desktop, and then round-robin the incoming requests between them.  The basic setup is easy enough, but I have no good solution for distributing the requests between the two web heads.

Is there any load balancing solution that I can run on Windows 7 Pro?

P.S. I can setup Server OS VMs and use Windows Load Balancing, but it would be so much more convenient to have it all contained on my desktop machine.

Comment: Why can't you have the VM's installed on your machine? It would still be contained on your desktop, but would be easier to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using perlbal as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/95427/windows-replacement-for-haproxy). Perlbal is pretty well respected, and perl runs well on windows, so it should be more than adequate. F5 also has a virtual appliance if you happen to be using BigIP in production.